# Can I run composer update in root folder and update all subfolder composer.json files?

Tags: composer-php

I have a WordPress app that has multiple plugins which are all built with OOP principles using Composer to manage autoloading in each plugin.

Now I'm wondering is it possible to just run

```
composer install --no-dev
```

in the project root, and somehow trigger running all the composer installs in the plugins so that the classmap is updated.

This is important when I want to deploy by pulling from a repository and performing the build using some kind of continuous integration.

Or do I need to manually specify in my deploy/build script to perform installation separately for each plugin?

Comment: That should work - but you could simply try this and see what happens ;)

Comment: This might be of use to you: https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that Wordpress still has no real Composer integration, which looks like a shame for everyone (including me) not involved in Wordpress development, but the project might have valid reasons, or it is no simple task (probably both).

That being said: You cannot run Composer in a directory level "one up" and mass-update the subdirectories. But it should only be a task of a simple shell script to iterate over all found directories, and if a `composer.json` is found inside, to update (or install) the dependencies.

My suggestion (including a random number of bugs) would be:

```
#!/bin/bash

for dir in {*,subdirA/*,subdirB/*}
do
  if [ -d $dir ]
  then
    pushd $dir
      if [ -f composer.json ]
      then
        composer install
      fi
    popd
  fi
done
```

Comment: Yeah, I was worried that it's not possible. Shell script it is. Thanks!